# What happened to bornological/uniform spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, soft-question, math-history, uniform-spaces

When reading older papers, I often see references to [bornological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space) or [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) spaces, which encode the notions of "boundedness" or "uniformness". In this way, they seem to sit between topological spaces and metric spaces.

It seems like these used to be of some amount of interest (they are explicitly mentioned in Rudin's "Functional Analysis" as topics he's omitting) so it seems odd to me that I've never heard them mentioned in a class, talk, etc. It might just be uncommon in my department, but I don't think I've ever seen them mentioned on MSE either, so they must be somewhat uncommon.

Looking at the axioms, they certainly *look* rather unwieldy, but you could say the same about lots of other mathematical objects which are quite well studied.

> What, then, happened to bornological spaces and uniform spaces?

Does anyone still do work in this area? Has it been subsumed by some other topic? This mystery haunts me.

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: Uniformity, of course, is still very much studied as it is the basis, e.g. of the notion of Cauchy sequences and uniformly continuous functions.  However it is my impression that, in all of the relevant places it appears, the uniform structure is provided by some much simpler feature:  the metric on a metric space, a fundamental system of neighborhoods of the origin in a TVS or a topological group, and so on, thus allowing one to avoid the intricate abstract definition of uniformity.  To my knowledge, the notion of uniform spaces per se hasn't found any great applications so far.

Comment: I agree with most of @Ruy's comment, all but the "intricate"; the definition of uniformity (in terms of entourages) looks quite natural to me. I'd add to his list of examples (metric spaces, TVS, etc.) that every compact topological space has a unique uniform structure.

Comment: As a student, when I learned the definition of entourages, it all seemed quite natural to me except for the axiom relating to the composition of entourages which I struggled like hell to understand. I was told to see it as a generalization of the triangle inequality but it took me a long time to feel comfortable with it. @AndreasBlass

Comment: @Ruy I usually think of the entourage axioms as generalizations of the definition of equivalence relation. The axiom about composition of entourages corresponds to the transitivity requirement for equivalence relations. Notice, for example, that a relation and its supersets form a uniform structure iff that relation is an equivalence relation.

Comment: In some areas of topological dynamics uniform spaces and their (Samuel) compactifications are still quite common

Comment: One could say that a fundamental interest in these notions is... uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 2):

When I first read your question, it seemed to me that uniform spaces were much more used than bornological spaces. But as I frequently use uniform spaces in my own research, I thought that my opinion might be biased and I looked for more measurable criteria.

(1) It turns out that both topics have their specific entry in the
[MSC2020-Mathematics Subject Classification System](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf):
**46A08** Barrelled spaces, bornological spaces,
**54E15** Uniform structures and generalizations.
A rough research on MathSciNet for these codes (since 2000) gives 43 entries for 46A08 and 229 entries for 54E15.

(2) A keyword research on MSE gives 316 results for "uniform space" but only 8 results for "bornological space". (the "_" are important: if you omit them and just look for *uniform space*, you get 8,297 results)

(3) The same research on Mathoverflow gives 98 results for "uniform space"
but only 6 results for "bornological space".

Also note there is a tag [uniform-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform-spaces)
on both MSE and Mathoverflow but no tag for "bornological-spaces".
All of this seem to confirm my original feeling.

Comment: I think "bornology" is a more helpful term to search for than "bornological space". But it still doesn't increase the amount of results by more than a factor of $3$ or $4$.